# Should there be a space before or after a <br> break (or none)?

Tags: html, whitespace, screen-readers

For a search engine or screen reader to read text should there be a space before or after a `<br>` break (or none at all)? If there isn't are they clever enough to insert a space - and not join the word before and after the `<br>` together?

1. Space is before

   ```html
   <h1>First bit of heading <br>rest of heading</h1>
   ```
2. Space is after

   ```html
   <h1>First bit of heading<br> rest of heading</h1>
   ```
3. No space. Will this get read as "First bit of headingrest of heading"?

   ```html
   <h1>First bit of heading<br>rest of heading</h1>
   ```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It makes no difference.

An explicit new line will be treated as a word break.

Comment: Why has this been marked down? Is this not correct?